# Removing {0,0,0} from expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression that results in something like this:

```
Subscript[A, 1] + 
 Subscript[x, 
  3] (Subscript[A, 1] Subscript[k, 11] + {0, 0, 0}[Subscript[x, 1], 
     Subscript[x, 2]]
```

For simplicity's sake,

```
out:= A1+x3(A1K11+ {0,0,0}[x1,x2])
```

All numbers are subscripts. I know that `{0,0,0}[x1,x2] =0`
How can I tell that to Mathematica? there are multiple instances of the same in my program so a general fix would be ideal.
Reiterating, I want to replace all instances of {0,0,0}[x1,xx2] with a zero

Comment: `exp = Subscript[A, 1] + 
  Subscript[x, 
    3] (Subscript[A, 1] Subscript[k, 11] + {0, 0, 0}[Subscript[x, 1], 
      Subscript[x, 2]]);  exp /. {0, 0, 0}[__] :> 0`?

Comment: TIP: never use `Subscript`.

Answer (score 5):

In your case, you can *match* the `{0,0,0}` exactly. Therefore, you can use replacements or `DeleteCases`:

```
expr = Subscript[A, 1] + 
  Subscript[x, 
    3] (Subscript[A, 1] Subscript[k, 11] + {0, 0, 0}[Subscript[x, 1], 
      Subscript[x, 2]])

expr /. {0, 0, 0}[___] :> 0

DeleteCases[expr, {0, 0, 0}[___], Infinity]
```

If you want to generalize this, you just have to ask yourself, how should the *pattern* look. For instance, let's say you have cases like `{0,0,1}` and `{1,0,3}` and you want to delete them as well, then you can make your matching broader by using:

```
{_Integer, _Integer, _Integer}[___] :> 0
```

The rule above reads as follow: Replace everything with 0 that has a list of 3 integers in the front, followed by anything or nothing at all in brackets (that is what `___` stands for).

Comment: How can I use Replacements? I have a similar problem with a case that's {0,0,1} instead of {0,0,0}. I'd like to understand a general method. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Also

```
expr /. {0 ..} -> (0 &)  
% // TeXForm
```

> $A_1 k_{11} x_3+A_1$

Comment: ... assuming, of course, that `{0,0,0}` appears only in the form `{0,0,0}[somethings]` in  `expr.`

Comment: How would I do the same for {0,0,1}[ ___]?

Comment: @Ashwin, you can use `{0,0,1}->(0&)` (again if `{0,0,1}` appears only as `{0,01}[...]`)